# W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://127.0.0.1:46090/1477397-541268.mp4 during video streaming

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-7.0-nougat

There are 2 problems during video streaming at android 7:

1. Video url is obfuscated at log cat (only at real devices, emulator doesn't obfuscate video url)
2. Default video app cannot stream video. chrome browser can.

Some notes:

1. Everything is ok at android 4.x - 6.x
2. I checked mpeg atoms. Everything is according to video streaming
   requirements
3. Video file size is in range 500kb-10mb
4. I used command `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://example.com/video.mp4?token=my_token" -t "video/*"` to start video at video app